# Ruby Selenium 2.0 cannot get value of input tag

Tags: ruby, selenium

Cannot get input tag value with Selenium 2.0 webdriver and Ruby.

`@driver.find_element(:id, "customer_info_last_name").text` returns nothing

and

`@driver.find_element(:id, "customer_info_last_name").value` yields unknown method error

what is the correct way to retrieve the value of an input tag?

Comment: What Ruby version are you using?

Answer (score 11):

How about this?

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "customer_info_last_name").attribute('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use driver.execute_script for getting inputs, instead of text or value.
Can you try with below way

```
<input name="cheese" type="text"/>
cheese = driver.find_element(:name, "cheese")
element = driver.execute_script("return $('.cheese')[0]")
```

Please ping me if you get any error message

Comment: the input tag has a value. but when I use:     

cheese = @driver.find_element(:name, "customer_info[last_name]")
element = @driver.execute_script("return $('.cheese')[0]")
print(element)

it prints NIL

Should I upgrade to Ruby 1.9.7?

Comment: On Document, they said Ruby 1.8.7 is fine, Can you try with Ruby 1.9. 2? and I am trying with 1.8.7, for me with 1.9.2 it is working fine

Comment: Thanks so much, but I forgot to mention that this is a Jquery site  <br><br>
so I got it to work with:  <br><br>
@driver.execute_script("return $('#customer_info_last_name').val()")

Comment: Almost all works done w/ execute_script and I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Also this should worked `@driver.find_element(:id, "customer_info_last_name")['value']`